# Liquid sloshing around in vacuum-packed mussels?

Tags: mussels

Loblaws sells these vaccuum-sealed mussels. When I pick them up with hand, I see much liquid sloshing inside.  Is this normal? Or something wrong with mussels?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see how much liquid is there. It could just be brine or seawater which would be ok, but considering the date of mid 2018 and the fact the the packet says "live" and "do not freeze" I would have to assume that they were frozen slowly by the retailer and the resulting large ice crystals damaged the flesh, causing the mussels to weep liquid upon thawing.

These would have to have been in quite a deep deep freeze to have a hope of being surely safe.

Comment: Just for the record, they were packed on 2018JN13 and are best before 2018JN28. I doubt they were frozen if they only last 2 weeks.

Comment: it's probably a generic image.